# Combining/Removing Edges

Tags: igraph, lattice, edges

I am creating a circular lattice graph and considering its corresponding full graph.  I call the edges in the full graph that are NOT in the lattice graph "non lattice" edges.  Now, I want to select a number of edges from the lattice to remove and then I want to add a number of randomly selected edges from the non lattice edges to create a NEW graph.  Here is a small example, you will see where it breaks down (last line).  Basically, I am having trouble with the edge lists being sequences.  Also, if I can do this without have to name all of the nodes that would be better- eventually, I will have large graphs!  Here is my current code:

```
n <- 5 #number of nodes
k <- 1 #number of neighbors for lattice connections

g <- make_lattice(length = n, dim = 1, nei = k, circular = TRUE) #lattice
V(g)$name <- letters[1:n]                 #name nodes
lat_e <- E(g)                             #lattice edges

g1 <- g                                   #make a copy
g1[V(g1), V(g1)] <- TRUE                  #add all possible edges
g1 <- simplify(g1)                        #remove loops
newe <- E(g1)   
non_lat_e <- difference(newe, olde)       #non lattice edges


n_switch <- 2                             #want to change 2 lattice edges to 
                                          non_lattice edges
e_rem <- sample(1:length(lat_e),n_switch)
e_add <- sample(1:length(non_lat_e), n_switch)

g <- delete_edges(g, lat_e[e_rem])       #delete lattice edges
g <- add.edges(g, non_lat_e[e_add])      #add non lattice edges. ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to nodes from one graph when adding edges to a new graph. You'll need to provide a pairwise vector by name in order to add new edges. Something like this

```
non_lattice_edges <- ends(g1, non_lat_e[e_add]) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.vector()

g <- add.edges(g, non_lattice_edges)
```

If you never delete a vector, then you don't need add vertex names because the vertex indices will stay consistent. Here is your code, but without the named vertices:

```
n <- 5 #number of nodes
k <- 1 #number of neighbors for lattice connections

g <- make_lattice(length = n, dim = 1, nei = k, circular = TRUE) #lattice

lat_e <- E(g)                             #lattice edges

g1 <- g                                   #make a copy
g1[V(g1), V(g1)] <- TRUE                  #add all possible edges
g1 <- simplify(g1)                        #remove loops
newe <- E(g1)   

non_lat_e <- difference(newe, lat_e)       #non lattice edges


n_switch <- 2                             
e_rem <- sample(1:length(lat_e),n_switch)
e_add <- sample(1:length(non_lat_e), n_switch)

g <- delete_edges(g, lat_e[e_rem])    #delete lattice edges


non_lattice_edges <- ends(g1, non_lat_e[e_add]) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.vector()

g <- add.edges(g, non_lattice_edges)
```